# How to search in multiple folders in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

In Windows Vista, you could easily select multiple non-indexed locations to search in. Where has this option been moved in Windows 7?

Comment: You can't, it doesn't provide that functionality due to the search overhaul.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fact: The default search user interface in Windows 7 was (re-)designed by morons. I *honestly* don't know how else to put it, and I'm being charitable here (and yes, I do know about [AQS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), thank you).

Turns out you *can* search multiple locations, but only *after* you've already searched for something once. Did I mention how idiotic the UI is? Basically, what I do is I search any folder for something I know does *not* exist, just to make the search fail as quickly as possible. This displays the following option:

[image: 1]

(Of course you'll see these options at the bottom after a successful search too, but when you want to search multiple locations and need to get to that **Custom** dialog quickly, it's best just to make the search fail ASAP.)

Now clicking on **Custom** will bring up this dialog:

[image: 2]

As you can see, it's easy enough to add/exclude folders here, and I just cannot fathom why no option has been provided to specify locations *before* conducting a search. If anyone can let me know of a hack or shortcut to get to this dialog directly, I'd be *highly* obliged.

Remember, if you need to search in non-indexed system directories, you'll have to select the appropriate option under Win Explorer's `Tools menu / Folder options / Search tab` or `Organize button-menu / Folder and search options / Search tab`:

[image: 3]

You can also save your search without any search terms specified, so that in future you can quickly search the same directories as before (with same exclusions if any) by launching the saved search from `C:\Users\<UserName>\Searches` (it's just an [XML file saved as .search-ms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb892885%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).